# i just want to slide, but i dont know how

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

since days i try to find a proper code to slide this images in the template but i couldnt make it happen, i need your help bro, lets make it burn.

Models 1 :

```
class MyFamily(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    explanatipon = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def photos(self):
        photos = [self.photo1, self.photo2, self.photo3, self.photo4, self.photo5]
        return [photo for photo in photos if photo is not None]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)[:30]
```

profile :

class Profile(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bio = models.TextField()
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.username)
```

views :

```
def photo(request):
    myfamily = MyFamily.objects.filter(active=True)

    context = {
        'myfamily':myfamily
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/create-form.html', context)
```

template :

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for photo in myfamily.photos %}
    <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ photo.url }}" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which part exactly are you having trouble with? Getting the photos to slide? Do you notice any errors in the console, or see any css files not loading?

Comment: @ben i can save the images, ican see the images in the admin panel BUT i cannot see any image at the carousel AND there are no error on the console.

Answer (score 1):

your view does not return a context:

```
def photo(request):
    myfamily = MyFamily.objects.filter(active=True)

    context = {
        'myfamily':myfamily
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/create-form.html', context)
```

Comment: @hermannthegerman yes thats the problem und ich weiss auch leider nicht weiter (and i dont know how to fix it).

Comment: {% for photo in myfamily.photos %}
   {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %} {{ photo.url }}
 {% endfor %} please try everything without the bootstrap and tell us if there is anything iterating. I cant really tell you, were the bottleneck is, because there are no errors

Comment: i tryed it BUT there are no error, i have made knowingly a error to see if the consol is working YES it gave me the error ( ı have write only to see {% endfor %}  as {% endforrrr %} ). Im not sure but i think there is something wrong with the views. I also added the context.

Comment: You can make a github repo with your code and send me the link. Maybe i can help you then